# Unity Unet Updating transform while clicked

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am currently trying to make a little drawing game where two players can draw at the same time over the network.

I am using a `GameObject` with a `TrailRenderer` to draw the lines.

Right now only the drawings of the host player are shown on both machines.

If a client player clicks and tries to draw I can see that a new object is spawned but the transform doesn't get updated. The spawned prefab has a `NetworkIdentity` (with Local Player Authority checked) and `NetworkTransform` attached to it. The following script is spawned by both players and also has a `NetworkIdentity` (with Local Player Authority checked).

I think I am actually doing something wrong with the `CmdTrailUpdate` and how to handle it but I can't really figure out what.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class TrailDrawer : NetworkBehaviour {

    private Plane objPlane;
    private GameObject currentTrail;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    public GameObject trail;

    public void Start()
    {
        objPlane = new Plane(Camera.main.transform.forward * -1, this.transform.position);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate() {
        if (isLocalPlayer) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
                CmdSpawn();
            } else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
                CmdTrailUpdate();
            }
        }
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdTrailUpdate() {
        Ray mRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float rayDistance;
        if (objPlane.Raycast(mRay, out rayDistance)) {
            currentTrail.transform.position = mRay.GetPoint(rayDistance);
        }
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdSpawn(){
        Ray mRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        float rayDistance;
        if (objPlane.Raycast(mRay, out rayDistance)) {
            startPos = mRay.GetPoint(rayDistance);
            currentTrail = (GameObject)Instantiate(trail, startPos, Quaternion.identity);
            NetworkServer.Spawn(currentTrail);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is:

`[Command]` means: Invoke the method from a client but only execute it on the server.

=> You are executing both methods `CmdSpawn` and `CmdTrailUpdate` only on the server.

**But:**

1. how shoud the server know your client's `Input.mousePosition`?
2. You don't want to raycast from the server's `camera.main`, but rather from the client's.

**Solution:**

1. Do both things local on the client and pass the position as parameter on the `[Cmd]` methods to the server.
2. Since you say the object already has a `NetworkTransform`, you wouldn't need to transmit the updated position to the server because `NetworkTransform` already does it for you. So calling `CmdTrailUpdate` from the client would not be neccesarry.

**But:** After spawning the object you have to tell the client who is calling `CmdSpawn`, which is his local `currentTrail` which's position he has to update. I would do this by simply passing the calling clients `gameObject` also to the `CmdSpawn` method and on the server call a `[ClientRpc]` method to set this client's `currentTrail` object.

(I'm assuming here, that the script you posted is attached diectly to the Player objects. If that is not the case, instead of the lines with `this.gameObject` you have to get the player's `gameObject` in a nother way.)

```cs
void FixedUpdate() {
    if (!isLocalPlayer) return;

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        // Do the raycast and calculation on the client
        Ray mRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        float rayDistance;
        if (objPlane.Raycast(mRay, out rayDistance)) {
            startPos = mRay.GetPoint(rayDistance);
                
            // pass the calling Players gameObject and the
            // position as parameter to the server
            CmdSpawn(this.gameObject, startPos);
        }
    } else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        // Do the raycast and calculation on the client
        Ray mRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            
        float rayDistance;
        if (objPlane.Raycast(mRay, out rayDistance)) {
            // only update your local object on the client
            // since they have NetworkTransform attached
            // it will be updated on the server (and other clients) anyway
            currentTrail.transform.position = mRay.GetPoint(rayDistance);
        }
    }
}

[Command]
private void CmdSpawn(GameObject callingClient, Vector3 spawnPosition){
    // Note that this only sets currentTrail on the server
    currentTrail = (GameObject)Instantiate(trail, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    NetworkServer.Spawn(currentTrail);

    // set currentTrail in the calling Client
    RpcSetCurrentTrail(callingClient, currentTrail);
}

// ClientRpc is somehow the opposite of Command
// It is invoked from the server but only executed on ALL clients
// so we have to make sure that it is only executed on the client
// who originally called the CmdSpawn method
[ClientRpc]
private void RpcSetCurrentTrail(GameObject client, GameObject trail){
    // do nothing if this client is not the one who called the spawn method
    if(this.gameObject != client) return;

    // also do nothing if the calling client himself is the server
    // -> he is the host
    if(isServer) return;

    // set currentTrail on the client
    currentTrail = trail;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the Command and Camera problems. I tried your code, but unfortunately it is not working completely. The problem now is, that currentTrail is null when i still hold the Mouse clicked. On the host it works perfectly and the lines get drawn on the host machine and the Client. On the client machine i get that null error and so the trail does not get drawn/transformed.

Comment: Hm it's difficult to debug it from here. Did you try to debug the calls one by one? (On the Client: is CmdSpawn called at all? -> on the Server is CmdSpawn running correctly with the correct parameters and RpcSetCurrentTrail called correctly? -> On the client again is RpcSetCurrentTrail executed with the correct parameters?)

So you have to use the Unity instance as clientonce and as host once to debug both sides

Comment: sent a bounty for great answer!  @LeoldeWire you should Tick an answer